# Can I fetch a phone number from Twitter Digits callback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter, twitter-digits

**Is it possible** to fetch user's phone number from Twitter Digits callback? I'm using http version and javascript to send SMS with twitter digits.

I only see next information response headers:

```
 {"oauth_echo_headers":{"X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization":"OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"gmoaaZhEG88hMQUdpWHnF1IAz\", oauth_nonce=\"3375731039-FmyAQgjhQG9rljUaXO3jBbiryF7dFQHeVL5oxu4gmoaaZhEG88hMQUdpWHnF1IAz1437035638029\", oauth_signature=\"TTbPlgipWdaNCSblfx0qznz%2B2Fc%3D\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1437035638\", oauth_token=\"3375731039-FmyAQgjhQG9rljUaXO3jBbiryF7dFQHeVL5oxu4\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"","X-Auth-Service-Provider":"https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you receive the credentials authorization header, you can query the server directly to receive attributes from the Digits service. Per the [docs](https://docs.fabric.io/web/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html):

```
/* Validate and log user in. */
function onLogin(loginResponse){
  // Send headers to your server and validate user by calling Digits’ API
  var oAuthHeaders = loginResponse.oauth_echo_headers;
  var verifyData = {
    authHeader: oAuthHeaders['X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization'],
    apiUrl: oAuthHeaders['X-Auth-Service-Provider']
  };

  $.post('/verify', verifyData)
    .done(function(){ window.reload(); });
}
```

You can see a sample of this in action in the [Cannonball web demo](https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-web/blob/master/public/javascripts/cannonball.js).

Answer (score 1):

May be its late but it can easily be achieved by putting following code wherever you want to fetch phone number:

```
String phone = Digits.getActiveSession().getPhoneNumber();
```